# submit normally newly created ajax form

Tags: php, ajax

I want to submit my form. In my form using first button I create a textbox through ajax and after that I use second button to submit the form normally. When I want to get the value of newly created textbox using $_POST it gives error. How can i get value of ajax created button on submission. my php code is :

```
<?php`enter code here`
 session_start();
  ob_start();
require_once "config.php";
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST")
{
if (isset($_POST['subtest']))
    {
        print $_GET['tt'];
    }
}
?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js">                     </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#subt").click(function(){
        jQuery("#divload").show();
        jQuery.ajax({url:"adp.php", type:"post", success:function(result){
        jQuery("#disp").html(result);
        jQuery("#divload").hide();
      }});
    return false;
    });
});

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#subtest").click( function() {
alert(jQuery("#tt").val());
});
});
</script>
</head>


<body id="#bdy">
<form id="FrmMain" method="post" action="">
<div id="Shd" style="font: 10%;  margin: 50px; background-repeat:repeat-y; padding-       left:120px;" >
    <input type="text" id="txtFrom" name="txtFrom" />
    <input type="text" id="txtUpto" name="txtUpto" />

    <input type="text" id="txtOpt" name="txtOpt" />
    <input type="submit" id="subt" name="subt" />
    <input type="submit" id="subtest" name="subtest" />
    <div id="RuBox" style="font-weight:bold;"><input type="checkbox" id="chkaccept"   name="chkaccept"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;I accept &nbsp;<a href="terms.html" style="color:#009;">terms and    conditions</a>.</div>

    </div>
   </form>
  <div style="color:#F00; font-size:18px; display:none;" id="divload">Please wait loaidng...   </div> 
   <div id="disp"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Code of my adp.php file :

```
<?php 
sleep(5);
?>
<div style="color:#30F; font-size:36px;">
 Application testing............
 <input type="text" id="tt" name="tt" />
 </div>
```

I am not getting value of textbox named "tt" in temp form

Thanks

Comment: can you post the error that you're getting? So the scenario is that you submit your form via ajax and then you generate  a new text field using ajax then you submit your form normally but then you're not getting the value of the text field that was generated from ajax. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty much not posting anything from here:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#subt").click(function(){
        jQuery("#divload").show();
        jQuery.ajax({url:"adp.php", type:"post", success:function(result){
        jQuery("#disp").html(result);
        jQuery("#divload").hide();
      }});
    return false;
    });
});
```

So I would assume that you only want to generate a text field dynamically. And you can do it without the use of ajax:

```
var form = $('#FrmMain');
$('<input>').attr({'type' : 'text', 'id' : 'tt', 'name' : 'tt'}).appendTo(form);
```

Plus you're also trying to print out `$_GET['tt']` while the form method is `POST`

```
if (isset($_POST['subtest']))
{
    print $_GET['tt'];
}
```

This should also be:

```
echo $_POST['tt'];
```